# Adding extra parameters to url src with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cant think in how i can do this some help please. 
I get some json objects and one of the values has html tags, some images, of course i cant fetch the images because they have relative urls, and the site it is host in a sub-domain. 
Is there any way to add the http://example.com/ to the already existing images/image.png

thanks

this is my json response:

```
description": "<img src=\"images/stories/Icons/Vacuum.png\" mce_src=\"images/stories/Icons/Vacuum.png\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Vacuum\" title=\"Vacuum\"> <img src=\"images/stories/Icons/Washing_Machine.png\" mce_src=\"images/stories/Icons/Washing_Machine.png\" border=\"0\" alt=\"Washing Machine\" title=\"Washing Machine\"></p>"

for(var i = 0; i < objJsonA.length; i++){
    var ap = objJsonA[i];
    var lot = ap.lot;
    $('.myclass').html(lot);
}
```

this returns 404 errors, the content i'm fetching it is on www.mysite.com and i am on m.mysite.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.location` to get the current server. For example, on the URL for this server in Chrome console I see:

```
> document.location
Location
ancestorOrigins: DOMStringList
assign: function () { [native code] }
hash: ""
host: "stackoverflow.com"
hostname: "stackoverflow.com"
href: "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13754450/adding-extra-parameters-to-url-src-with-jquery"
origin: "http://stackoverflow.com"
pathname: "/questions/13754450/adding-extra-parameters-to-url-src-with-jquery"
port: ""
protocol: "http:"
reload: function () { [native code] }
replace: function () { [native code] }
search: ""
toString: function toString() { [native code] }
valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }
__proto__: Location
```

So you could use:

```
var image = '/images/abc.jpg';
var url = document.location.origin + image;
// url is now 'http://stackoverflow.com/images/abc.jpg'
```

There are a lot of plugins for working with URLs in JavaScript/jQuery and it probably makes sense to use one of them ([example search](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+url+plugin)).